# Error while uploading ios application from xcode

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode10

while i am trying to upload the archived app with application loader i got this error
Application Loader is unable to upload your package
You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request.
In info.plist i have the Bundle identifier, i am using xcode 10.0

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Any specific reason to use the Application Loader? I would probably prefer uploading via XCode itself.

Comment: Still, have you gone through all the available solutions/reasons for this error on Google? [you must supply a cfbundleidentifier for this request](https://www.google.com/search?q=you+must+supply+a+cfbundleidentifier+for+this+request&oq=you+must+supply&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3945j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: First i was trying with xcode and i got this error 
App Store Connect Operation Error
Could not find the main bundle or the Info.plist is missing a CFBundleIdentifier in '/var/folders/0v/555jjj1n6jxbhrh72lq81bjh0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.Kcz/Packages/App.ipa'.

Comment: i tried almost everything i found but the same error, new provisining profile, new cert, add APPL to bundle creator OS type  code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tried every solution i found, finally by removing iOS platform and adding again fixed the problem.

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: Can you please explain more?